# InnoSetup: Find out reason for restart

Tags: inno-setup, restart

I have an Inno Setup script that installs my application and its accompanying files. 
On some systems a restart is required, on some not. 
I would like to find out the reason for the required restart. 
How would I do this most intelligently?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just for debugging? You can peek in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations to see if there are queued moves/deletes awaiting the next reboot

Comment: @Alex, there's no direct way to determine it from the InnoSetup script, so it could be the answer.

Comment: Yes, please set it as "answer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can peek inside

`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations`

to see if there are any moves/renames/deletes queued for the next reboot.

([Sysinternals utility viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Use `/LOG` when you run the install and then look at the log file that it generates (by default in `%TEMP%`).  It should fairly clearly show in there which files were queued for replacement on restart, or which other reasons caused a restart request to be issued.

Usually restarts are triggered by overuse of `restartreplace` without using something like `AppMutex` to ensure that the application has been shut down properly before installing, or from subinstalls executed during `[Run]`.